# Python script crashes when called from crontab

Tags: python-3.x, cron, imagemagick, digital-ocean, moviepy

I have a script (hosted on DigitalOcean ubuntu 18.04.3 droplet) executing from crontab which looks something like this

> 0 5 * * * cd /home/john/clips/; /home/john/clips/venv/bin/python3 /home/john/clips/clip_compilator.py

And it works but once it reaches the following line inside one of the scripts

```
name = mp.TextClip(f"John".upper(), 
    color='#6441A4', 
    stroke_color="black", 
    align='West',
    fontsize=90, 
    font='BigNoodleTitling', method='label')\
                        .margin(left=95, opacity=0)\
                        .set_position(("left", "top"))
```

it crashes with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/clips/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py", line 1161, in __init__
    subprocess_call(cmd, logger=None)
  File "/home/john/clips/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/tools.py", line 46, in subprocess_call
    proc = sp.Popen(cmd, **popen_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'unset': 'unset'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/clips/clip_compilator.py", line 44, in <module>
    current_clip.add_videofile(add_text(current_clip))
  File "/home/john/clips/clip_editor.py", line 16, in add_text
    fontsize=90, font='BigNoodleTitling', method='label')\
  File "/home/john/clips/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py", line 1170, in __init__
    raise IOError(error)
OSError: MoviePy Error: creation of None failed because of the following error:

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'unset': 'unset'.

.This error can be due to the fact that ImageMagick is not installed on your computer, or (for Windows users) that you didn't specify the path to the ImageMagick binary in file conf.py, or that the path you specified is incorrect
```

When I run the same command in bash (outside of the crontab) everything works fine.
For some reason it crashes on the `TextClip` specifically and I don't know why.
Some have suggested the solution might be commenting out a specific line in the `policy.xml` of ImageMagick but my `convert -list policy` output is this:

[image]

Comment: Is there an `unset` binary distributed with ImageMagick? (It actually seems more like maybe it's relying on an [`unset` shell command](https://ss64.com/bash/unset.html)..? If so, maybe there is a different default shell that is not compatible.. what does the source code look like? :D)

Comment: @user2864740 Do you mean the source code of the python script or the crontab?

Comment: The code that uses / attempts to use "unset".

Comment: Regardless, what is `/bin/sh` (pointing to)? If it's not `bash`, it might be worth a go to try and have it be.. making several assumptions of what the underlying code is doing.

Comment: @user2864740 I've updated the full error code, I could update the source code too but I've been debugging it for hours and the line right above the one in question prints out fine but it never goes further than that

Comment: @user2864740 Sorry for being such a newbie but how do I test where `/bin/sh` is pointing to?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/328364/bin-sh-is-a-symbolic-link-that-doesnt-point-to-bin-bash - use `ls -l /bin/sh` to show where it points to. Relinking it somewhere else is *global* change. Also, if said target supports `unset` then I would leave it alone (see the appropriate manual).

Comment: @user2864740 I've run it and it said `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Oct 21 15:48 /bin/sh -> dash` . Will changing it to bash effect the `unset` error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by adding

```
from moviepy.config import change_settings
change_settings({"IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY": "/usr/local/bin/convert"})
```

to the top of the `clip_editor.py` which had the line that was causing the error as per [tomasdms's](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/347) solution